# Spring boot session management for login using redis

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

How to use redis for session management as i am trying to make an ecommerce website using reactjs and springboot. I need my login to be maintained when page reloads that is why I am trying using redis but can anyone of you please help me to solve this as whatever I've tried using different ways to manage the session but is lost once the page reloads. My session forms on the browser as well as on the redis server but when i reload the page, it goes off. FYI I am using mysql as my primary data storage

I just want that when i reload the page or go to another page, my login stays.